# Understanding dependency injection

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

I've been reading about the benefits of implementing DI on iOS, but I have one doubt: where should I put the code that actually creates instances of objects? Is it factory pattern the recommended way to go about this? should all instances be created on the same factory? I've been checking out some frameworks like Typhoon but they all seem over-engineered to me for something as simple as dependency injection. I don't want to overwhelmed my app by using any of these frameworks, so I'm trying to keep it simple, at least for now.

Comment: Use a DI framework. Don't reinvent this wheel.

Comment: Keeping it simple sounds like a good plan. Use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) and compose your application in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot).